# Proof of loss of orthogonality in Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, floating-point, gram-schmidt

I am stuck at understanding about how to derive the following proofs related to error bounds which are given in the following slides. Can anyone please explain to me how these are derived?

[image: Slide]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to how to prove the three inequalities given in the slides for loss of orthogonality. Like for vector inner product there is floating point error bound mu + O(u^2) where m is size of column vector and u is machine epsilon.

Comment: Please consider transcribing the slide and providing a link to the source.